# Import values from named ranges from different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, named-ranges

I have the following code that aims to import ranges from a different workbook into the current one. They share the same named range names but it might be that they are in different worksheets.

My code for the sub looks like this:

```
Sub ImportWorkbookRanges()
Dim ws As Workbook, wbI As Workbook
Dim arrRanges As Variant, i As Integer

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
[...]Workbook File to Import[...]
Set wbI = ActiveWorkbook
wb.Activate

arrRanges = Array("NamedRange1", "NamedRange2", "NamedRange3")
For i = LBound(arrRanges) To UBound(arrRanges)
    [...]Here code to import the values[...]
Next i

wbI.Close False
End Sub
```

Now the import code ideally looks like this:
`wb.Range(arrRanges(i)) = wbI.Range(arrRanges(i))`

This doesn't work so I need to find another way that works.
Anyone with a solution? I was thinking about looping through the Named Ranges in the respective workbook but that seems to be an inefficient solution.

Comment: Do you know the names of the workbooks in advance? If not, are they open, so that you can iterate over them without knowing the names?

Comment: I would be able to iterate over the names in the import workbook, i.e. `wbI` is the name of the opened workbook from which we want to import the values. I would be able to go through all the names in there and choose accordingly. I am not sure if that is the most efficient way though.

Comment: Won't something like this work?

    `For Each book in Workbooks
        For i = LBound(arrRanges) To UBound(arrRanges)
            wb.Range(arrRanges(i)) = book.Range(arrRanges(i))
        Next i
    Next book`

Comment: No, the range needs a worksheet to work with.

Comment: Of course, my mistake. So are the named ranges in the different workbooks in different sheets, or does the sheet that contain them have the same name in all workbooks? If so a static reference to the name of the sheet ought to work.

Another idea might be to create to arrays with workbook names/paths and sheet names and then iterate over both arrays.

Comment: The problem is that the sheets might differ between all the workbooks and they are dynamic. I think I have to use the iterate through names way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using Excel 2016 you wouldn't need VBA to do that - just go natively via Get Data with this code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("SourcepathOfYourFile"), null, true),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Kind] = "DefinedName") and ([Item] = "DefinedName1" and [Item] = "DefinedName2"and [Item] = "DefinedName3")),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Data", {"Column1"}, {"Column1"})
in
    #"Expanded Data"
```

If your named ranges contain more than 1 column, you would have to choose them as well in the last step. These operations can also easily be done via the UI only.

For earlier Excel-Versions you would need to install the Power Query-AddIn: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379&CorrelationId=8191753b-a127-467e-a962-7823aecec9ec

It's also easy to collect the named ranges from multiple files if this is needed.

Comment: Forgot to add to the tags that I am using 2010, we are only updating in a couple of months.

Comment: So then you would need to install the Power Query-Add in from the link above.